# what is the correct procedure to setup first nextjs app

Tags: reactjs, installation, next.js

I've been trying to create a `Nextjs app`. The command I've been using or which once worked `npx create-next-app` throws:

Note: node -v 14.18.0

```
Using yarn.

Installing dependencies:
- react
- react-dom
- next

'yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
events.js:377
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: spawn yarn ENOENT
at notFoundError (C:\Users\Degamber\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-next- 
app\dist\index.js:100:3828)
at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\Degamber\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-next- 
app\dist\index.js:100:4207)
at ChildProcess.e.emit (C:\Users\Degamber\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-next- 
app\dist\index.js:100:4062)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:282:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
at ChildProcess.e.emit (C:\Users\Degamber\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-next- 
app\dist\index.js:100:4103)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:282:12) {
code: 'ENOENT',
errno: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'spawn yarn',
path: 'yarn',
spawnargs: [
'add',
'--exact',
'--cwd',
'C:\\Users\\Degamber\\Downloads\\xyz\\nextjs-blog',
'react',
'react-dom',
'next'
]
}
PS C:\Users\Degamber\Downloads\xyz>
```

otherwise the document says use this : `npx create-next-app nextjs-blog --use-npm --example "https://github.com/vercel/next-learn/tree/master/basics/learn-starter"`
although it works but I want to make it setup easily using `npx create-next-app`

Comment: I think you need to install yarn , here might help https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install

Comment: I don't use `yarn`.It is available for `npm`. I need it for npm only.

Answer (score 2):

This will fix it and allow you to keep using npm.

```
npx create-next-app@latest --use-npm
```

[Reference](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/35607)

Comment: Thanks! This works however I don't know if this is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

downgrade from the latest, install a prior version:

```
npx create-next-app@11.1.4 appname
```

Comment: This causes the same problem again.